# Absolute Positioning of other Element causes weird Image Spacing by 1px

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have been trying to add an overlay play icon to my videos which all works however after adding this im getting a weird 1px spacing on the bottom row of my images

When the absolute positioning is removed from (#icon) the images align perfectly - but when added back it adds the weird spacing

Could anybody help with this?

**CODE: http://www.codeply.com/go/JC75OR4xpD**

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="instaVideos">
            <h1>Short Videos</h1>

                <a href="http://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t50.2886-16/11661388_407770589406910_367605487_n.mp4" class="html5lightbox">
                    <img src="https://igcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t51.2885-15/11325016_1163164417043690_1908545167_n.jpg"/>
                    <img id="icon" src="img/youtubePlayIcon.png"/>
                </a>


                <a href="http://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xtp1/t50.2886-16/1489765_333969910114258_1680134671_n.mp4" class="html5lightbox">
                    <img src="https://igcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/t51.2885-15/10706968_601233316654119_1567865956_n.jpg"/>
                    <img id="icon" src="img/youtubePlayIcon.png"/>

                </a>

                <a href="http://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t50.2886-16/10679292_519402934860781_468618633_n.mp4" class="html5lightbox">
                    <img src="https://igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t51.2885-15/10665576_441425795996740_1661178998_n.jpg"/>
                    <img id="icon" src="img/youtubePlayIcon.png"/>

                </a>

                <a href="http://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfp1/t50.2886-16/10641919_684721938283340_2079757675_n.mp4" class="html5lightbox">
                    <img src="https://igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/t51.2885-15/924582_890120924350870_1658010424_n.jpg"/>
                    <img id="icon" src="img/youtubePlayIcon.png"/>

                </a>


                <a href="http://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfp1/t50.2886-16/10541299_371884109631916_1548975081_n.mp4" class="html5lightbox">
                    <img src="https://igcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t51.2885-15/10538735_664550930296554_1249448005_n.jpg"/>
                    <img id="icon" src="img/youtubePlayIcon.png"/>

                </a>

                <a href="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t50.2886-16/11683107_112731029066100_1538573428_n.mp4" class="html5lightbox">
                    <img src="https://igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/t51.2885-15/11386568_1455668744729300_108311835_n.jpg"/>
                    <img id="icon" src="img/youtubePlayIcon.png"/>

                </a>

                <a href="http://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfp1/t50.2886-16/10721731_1471532036461241_1447645097_n.mp4" class="html5lightbox">
                    <img src="https://igcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t51.2885-15/10724656_765518650158719_1752400817_n.jpg"/>
                    <img id="icon" src="img/youtubePlayIcon.png"/>

                </a>

                <a href="http://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t50.2886-16/11679305_467034590127593_1579081935_n.mp4" class="html5lightbox">
                    <img src="https://igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t51.2885-15/11429736_699224963557660_1457167025_n.jpg"/>
                    <img id="icon" src="img/youtubePlayIcon.png"/>

                </a>

        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.instaVideos {
            margin:0 auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            max-width: 800px;
            width:90%;
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
            transition:all .2s ease-in-out;

        }


        .instaVideos > h1 {
            margin:0 auto;
            text-align: left;
            width:300px;
            margin-left: 2%;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-family: 'raleway';
        }

        .instaVideos > a > img {
            width:150px;
            height:auto;
            margin-top: 5px;
            border:1px solid red;
            text-align: center;
        }


        .instaVideos a:hover {
            opacity: 0.7;
        }


        .instaVideos > a {
            position:relative;
        }



        #icon {
            width:auto;
            height:30px;
            position:absolute !important;
            left:35%;
            top:0px;
            right:0px;
            display:inline !important;
        }
```

**SOLVED**

I fixed this by doing the follwing:

```
.instaVideos {
    position:relative;
}

#icon {
 position: absolute;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this help you: [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/oosmhhpr/)

CSS:

```
.instaVideos > a {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      width: auto;
      display: inline-block;
}
#icon {
    width:auto;
    height:30px;
    position:absolute !important;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! That did fix it! Would you be able to explain what the issue was to better my understanding of this situation?

Comment: The problem is the a element, because that element don't have block properties, in the moment that we added `display: inline-block` to a tag all work how we want... sorry for my explain but my english is really bad... :(((